# Generate an HTML tree from JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a one-file website... We all know bandwidth and internet are... yeah... That's why I only render parts of user interface when needded. Now I wanna take a step further and use JSON to store small parts of my website (trees of html elements) and generete the actual HTML on demand.

But I'm struggling to figure out how to "convert" the JSON object into plain old HTML. I found many topics and answers on how to achieve this, but none of those solved problems. I need a solution that could generate trees with ANY number of chid elements, inside of child elements and so on... All these solutions used `.innerHTML` which could literally void all my event handlers. I found nothing I wouldn't know already...

The JSON notation would look like this:

```js
var htmlTree = {
 'type': 'section',
 'attr': {
  'id': 'someID',
  'class': 'someClass'
 },
 'content': 'section name',
 'children': [
  {
   'type': 'h1',
   'attr': {
    'class': 'heading'
   },
   'content': 'Heading',
   'children': [
    {
     'type': 'span',
     'content': 'text'
    },
    {
     'type': 'span',
     'content': 'more text'
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

And the result would look like this:

```html
<section id="someID" class="someClass">
 section name
 <h1 class="heading">
  Heading
  <span>text</span>
  <span>more text</span>
 </h1>
</section>
```

Does anybody know a solution to this problem? I really don't want to use any frameworks or libraries. I know it's a little hard to do something like this, that's why I'm asking here...

Comment: This is actually not hard at all.  It involves [traversing the tree](https://hackernoon.com/5-techniques-to-iterate-over-javascript-object-entries-and-their-performance-6602dcb708a8) and emitting content based exactly on how its described in the JSON.

Comment: It sounds like you're really trying to reinvent the wheel and achieve something based on false premises. Using a JSON data structure to generate your website is pretty much a costlier version of doing it in native HTML at this point. Better bandwidth optimizations lie on the way your HTML is served, for example by using gzip compression.

Comment: Why hard? This is really easy. 1) Just turn that JSON into JavaScript object via `window.parseJSON()` 2) Then just Iterate over that object and create html tags from there

Comment: @PaulStenne Yes but I wnna use JSON because this way I can avoid rendering gigabytes of data at once (and everything is served using only ONE HTML file) Imagine that stackoverflow would render this exact page 20 times but with different images and titles. that's what I wanna avoid.

Comment: @Yang Could you please tell where should I start? or find anybody who would know such stuff.

Comment: Just search for recursing JSON objects; that's all this is. That said: you will be saving little (if any) in the way of bandwidth; HTML compresses very, very well. Your example gzips (with defaults) to 185 bytes for the JSON, 129 bytes for the HTML.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm starting to lose hope in humanity...The data MUST be stored in JSON because I cant just pop it right onto the website. AS I SAID, this whole website is stored in one HTML file and I can't render EVERYTHING at once, just small parts of it like popup windows and messages. I though of storing the whole html tree just as a string in a variable, but this way I would have to useo use `innerHTML` to render the content, which I wanna avoid...

Comment: @FalsePrice All of which can be handled via hiding and showing, wrapping functionality in functions (e.g., template builders) and so on. You say "MUST" but you and I use that word very differently. There are any number of "one-file websites" that don't store their entire site in JSON, e.g., any Gatsby site. Like I said: you're backing yourself into a corner.

Comment: @DaveNewton If I wrote everything inside this html file, I wouldn't be able to manage it easly... AND WHY are people always talking about other ways of doing something, if I just wanna know how to solve it IN ONE SPECIFIC WAY... You helped me with nothing, why did you try in the first place?

Comment: @FalsePrice Oh, I'm sure managing it in a non-standardized JSON file will be much easier. Good luck! To answer why people are talking about other ways of doing something--because so far nobody thinks this is a viable solution, and will lead to more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: And again--this is a simple recursive structure, any tree-oriented recursion tutorial will have this sorted out in minutes.

Comment: Ok, So what do you mean by non-standardized? You have the opportunity to really help me...

Comment: @FalsePrice You're throwing away working and vetted standards that can handle everything brought up so far, in favor of a home-grown solution that may or may not be able to do what you want. This is 2019: there are any *number* of ways to do what you're asking while still delivering a single file to the client, and you haven't brought up anything regarding why any of those solutions aren't what you want (and at least one reason, event handlers, why making something up *isn't* a good idea). Recursion over a tree is easy, so if this is really the route you think you "MUST" go, then go.

Answer (score 2):

Bandwidth is cheap nowadays as the server supports gzip it takes even less. Why combine with more engaging Json and libraries to create HTML?

Instead of processing JSON, inject ready (parts) html - loaded via Ajax.

Try
http://www.json2html.com

You can try something like this but this make sense only if you have many same rows (and your data is really simple).

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="ct"></div>
<script>
var data = [{ 
    "id" : 1,
    "f" : "Arya",
    "l" : "Stark"
},
{ 
     "id" : 1,
    "f" : "Jon",
    "l" : "Snowk"
}];

var parent = document.getElementById("ct");

data.forEach( function (row) {
 
 newDiv = document.createElement("div");
 newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>" + row.f + " " + row.l + "</h1>";
 parent.append(newDiv);  
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Json is more compact than HTML, even gzipped. I just wanna know if there is a good way to achieve my goal *without* using any external frameworks/libraries. If you know any good ways, then I would really appreciate your help. Plus the bandwidth isn't really cheap in my country... as it's in 40% just a forest and small valleys with internet over phone cables... Which is 5Mb/s here... Thing again... Cheap?

Comment: I compare your JSON (minified) 245 B:  and HTML 136 B. https://pastebin.com/MCJKkq5D    Of course after gzipped results can be other. You can write own parser (or use library) in JS and build elements one by one, acording your data. Or prepare HTML ready in backend.

Comment: And another thing, I could just store the whole html tree as a string in a variable, but then I would have to use `innerHTML` to render those, which could ruin the event handlers.

Comment: @FalsePrice I really don't think you've completely thought this through. You're either going to need a non-HTML representation of the bits you want to render, or HTML. If you have complex event handling you can't do via normal event bubbling, you're backing yourself into a corner. So all the data will be there anyway--just hide or show it. I just don't believe there's any point to what you're doing, and there's not enough detail in the question to suggest what you're doing is a valuable exercise.

Comment: @FalsePrice added a small snippet. Maybe you should consider dividing the page into subpages, using browser-side caching - PWA elements. maybe that would reduce the amount of bandwidth. Good luck.

Comment: @FalsePrice Sorry, I'm clearly too stupid to help. Goodbye.

Comment: @FalsePrice Btw, including adding indentation to the output, and using two functions from lodash, and assuming text output instead of DOM object creation (e.g., `console.log`), the function is about a dozen lines long. Turning that into actual DOM objects would add on maybe another dozen lines depending. Here's the thing: if you think that your site is so non-trivial that you need to break with already-working solutions then, in theory, you're educated enough to be able to figure out recursion without asking someone to write it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The [`JSON.parse` reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter) can be used to transform key value pairs in JSON string :

```js
var json = '{"type":"section","attr":{"id":"someID","class":"someClass"},"content":"section name","children":[{"type":"h1","attr":{"class":"heading"},"content":"Heading","children":[{"type":"span","content":"text"},{"type":"span","content":"more text"}]}]}'

var el = JSON.parse(json, function(k, v) {
  if (!v.type) return v
  
  var el = document.createElement(v.type)
  el.textContent = v.content
  
  for (k in v.attr || {})
    el.setAttribute(k, v.attr[k])
    
  for (var c of v.children || []) 
    el.append('\n', c)
    
  return el
})

document.body.innerHTML = el.outerHTML
console.log( el.outerHTML )
```